# Hibernate - Execute anonymous PL/SQL block

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, plsql

How do I execute the following PL/SQL block using hibernate(SessionFactory/NamedParameterJDBCTemplate)

```
declare
 a number := :a;
 b number := :b;
begin
 insert into tab1 values(a,b);
end;
/
```

Comment: You are more interested on the effect of insertation or strict the exeuction of the code ?

Comment: Why are you using an anonymous block?

Comment: I have to export data from one db to another(both have identical schema), lot of dynamic sequences will be generated by my export tool. So, I can successfully execute generated anonymous block using sqlplus. But, I am not sure how to proceed with hibernate.

Comment: Hibernate is completely the wrong tool for managing data migrations.  You want something suited to batch operations.

Answer (score -1):

Use store procedure call:

**Mysql proc:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `mySProc`(param VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
...
END
```

**Java Hibernate Query:**

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
    "CALL mySProc(:param)")
    .addEntity(MyClass.class)
    .setParameter("param", "7277");
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I am using oracle, also I generate PL/SQL dynamically in-order to export form one db to another.